# how to check between times in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

This query works fine in all case expect one condition  For example 
StartDate 2017-04-17 09:00:00 and endDate 2017-04-17 10:00:00 it ll take it is correct and if v enter StartDate 2017-04-17 09:05:00  and endDate  2017-04-17 09:50:00 it will not allow its correct  but if i enter the time between StartDate 2017-04-17 10:30:00  and endDate  2017-04-17 011:30:00 it should be allowed as time only 9 to 10 exists and not 10.30 to 9.30 so how to allow this
input

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from TableDTO where cName =? and ((date(startDate) between date(:std) AND date(:etd))AND (HOUR (startDate)  BETWEEN :stDate AND :edDate))or((date(endDate) between date(:std) AND date(:etd))AND( HOUR (endDate)  BETWEEN :stDate AND :edDate))");
        query.setParameter(0, timeTableDTO.getClassName()); 
        query.setParameter("std", timeTableDTO.getStartDate()); 
        query.setParameter("etd", timeTableDTO.getEndDate());   

        query.setParameter("stDate",  starthr);
        query.setParameter("edDate", endthr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write **HQL**.

ResultTransformer transform the generated query result to model and
set parameter is a placeholder of query parameter.

```
Query query =  ((SQLQuery) getSession().createSQLQuery(
                "select First_name,Last_name,email_id from tabletbl  where (date(StartDate) between date('2017-04-17 08:05:00') AND
    date('2017-04-17 08:50:00')
    AND HOUR (StartDate) BETWEEN 8 AND 9) or(date(EndDate) between
    date('2017-04-17 08:05:00') AND
    date('2017-04-17 08:50:00')
    AND HOUR (EndDate) BETWEEN 8 AND 9) ).
                setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(tabletbl.class))).                
                setParameter("StartDate", StartDate);    
List<tabletblModelClass> list = query.list();
```

Comment: here i want to set values date('2017-04-17 08:50:00' here) not to date(StartDate)

Comment: you can set date like startDate= :startDate.

Comment: okk i got it see my updated question i have another problem with this query

Answer (score 0):

You can use Criteria like below with a greater-or-equal and less-or-equal combination `ge` and `le` :

```
// assuming startdate and endDate are Date objects with the values in them as you wish. and your Criteria is called criteria
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate", startDate)); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("startDate", endDate));
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `Restrictions.between`

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("startDate",startDate,endDate);
```

documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) ...

> static Criterion
>   between(String propertyName, Object lo, Object hi)
>
> Apply a "between" constraint to the named property

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i ll try it